# how to create dynamic tile content with struts2

Tags: struts2, tiles

i m using struts 2 and tiles to build a small application, i m using a simple layout header + body + footer, i have to display some dynamic information (menu, logged in user information, etc.) in the application header. So what is the best way to do that ? avoid duplicate code, header logic separation etc.
- do i have to use tiles view preparer ?
- create a custom interceptor that implements the common functionality? if yes, how to do that if a already have a user bean and menu bean?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 documentation should help you get started http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/tiles-plugin.html

Comment: the documentation is just about using tiles with struts2, i m looking for the best way to make a tile more dynamic, like calling a header or a footer class every time this tile are rendered.

Comment: @Moam: Struts2 has nothing to do with this.plugin work as a bridge between Struts2 and Tiles and you are free t use tiles way you want.I believe your question is more about Tiles and not struts2